# Accessing Fields of a has_one relation Silvestripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have a DataObject `Team` that has a `has_one` relation to `Member`. I would like to use the ORM to search Team but be able to filter records by the value of one field of the related Member table. Just to be more clear, I can achieve the same result with SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Member 
LEFT JOIN Team ON Team.MemberID=Member.ID 
  WHERE Member.CityID=142 
  AND Team.Target='Boy'
  AND Team.GenreID=51 
  AND Team.Fyr <= 9 
  AND Team.Tyr >= 9
```

Okay, I got it. The answer is:

```
$teams= Team::get()->filter(array('Member.CityID:ExactMatch' => $var));
```

and later simply filter `$teams`

Comment: Please provide your answer as an answer and not as part of your question… you can accept your own answer later on.

Comment: Ok, sorry, no experience on stack yet.